# One NavigatorController is enough?

Tags: xcode, uinavigationcontroller

Currently im working in a Iphone app project and I have a simple question but i couldn't resolve with google. 
It is correct to use only one NavigatorController in a storyboard or it's clean to use more than one.
I just want to activate the NavigationControl in certain situations like configuration and edit profile (examples). 
Thanks.

Comment: You need to elaborate your needs. Sometimes it's enough, sometimes it's not.

Comment: Keep only one thing in mind whenevr you will use prepareforsegue at that time navigationcontroller needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only need one at a time, but it depends if you should use more than one.

If you only show a `UINavigationController` on some special not directly connected scenes you **can** use the same, but you shouldn't.

For example: If you have a *main menu*, an *options screen* and a *address book screen* as single scenes, you should create a NavigationController for every scene - when needed - and destroy it, when going back to the main menu.
It can however be more efficient to reuse the same NavigationController if you need one in every scene of some connected scenes, best example I know of is that there is a NavigationController in an `UITabBarController`. Say you only need to show a NavigationController when the scene with the TabBarController is shown, Apple says

> An app that uses a tab bar controller can also use navigation controllers in one or more tabs. When combining these two types of view controller in the same user interface, the tab bar controller always acts as the wrapper for the navigation controllers.

[Link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/CombiningViewControllers.html)

#### So I would suggest:

Use more than one if they can be logically separated.